# Does fit_generator equals to fit loop function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I build a model with keras. I use `fit_generator` to train my model and get good results with mean accuracy of 0.9.

`net.fit_generator(train_it.generator(), epoch_iterations * batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=val_it.generator())`

But when I replaced fit_generator by fit loop function, training became slower (1/10 speed). And the results became worse (mean accuracy is 0.8, some categories is good and some are far worse) and the accuracy curve fluturated greatly.

```
        x, y = next(train_it.generator())
        valid_data = next(val_it.generator())
        net.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=valid_data)
```

Can anyone explain it? I thought `fit_generator` should be the same as `fit loop function`, but it seems that the two training methods may not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

They are not necessarily the same. Fit loop will evenly fit through the whole dataset(once every data point). If you used custom generator, and used `random.sample`(or something similar), fit generator will unevenly choose from the training data. This will cause some difference.

And evaluate using custom generator that uses  will `random.sample` will cause a lot difference. Still, same theory, evaluate_generator will choose randomly among the test set. But this time, it is evaluating!

Comment: In my custom `dataset generator`, I did not use `random.sample` or soomething similar. I am sure that my `fit_generator` use the same training samples and order with `fit loop`. So I donot think it is because of the difference of datasets.

Comment: `np.random.choice`?? If not, try training it again, sometimes results just varies because cuda don't have reproducibility.